# Tomita-Takesaki versus Frobenius: where is the similarity?

Tags: field-with-one-element, von-neumann-algebras, intuition

I've often heard Alain Connes say that the modular flow of Tomita-Takesaki theory should be thought of as a characteristic zero analog of the Frobenius endomorphism. 
 ... can anyone justify this claim?

> Given a von Neumann algebra $M$, its **modular flow**
>   is a canonically defined homomorphism
>   $$
> \mathbf{\Phi}: i\mathbb R\quad\longrightarrow\quad \text{BIM}^\times(M)
> $$
>   that, in the presence of a state (or weight), lifts to a homomorphism $i\mathbb R\to Aut(M)$.
>   Here, $\text{BIM}^\times(M)$ denotes the [2-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-group) of invertible $M$-$M$-bimodules.
>   The bimodule $\mathbf{\Phi}(it)$ is the non-commutative $L^p$-space for the value $\frac 1 p=it$.
>
> ---
>
> Given a ring $R$ of characteristic $p$, its **Frobenius** is a canonically defined homomorphism
>   $$
> \mathbf{F}:\mathbb N\quad\longrightarrow\quad End(R)
> $$
>   such that $\mathbf{F}(1)$ sends $x$ to $x^p$.
>   More generally, $\mathbf{F}(n)$ sends $x$ to $x^{p^n}$.

So far, the only analogy I can see is that both $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ are canonically defined actions...

Comment: minor nitpick: typo in title

Comment: That's an interesting question. Personally, I don't understand/know what "the  $\mathbb F_1$ Frobenius" should give (just archimedean factors or the whole completed zeta function?)
But in the framework of Endomotives Connes (together with Consani and Marcolli) developed a (co)homological approach (based on cyclic homology) which leads to a spectral realization of zetas in form of a canonical $R$-action on a certain homology group which might be considered as an analogue of Frobenius action on l-adic cohomology.
This is explained in http://alainconnes.org/docs/bookwebfinal.pdf pp. 556.

Comment: This may not be of much help (and perhaps you already know the article better than I do) but in his article for the "IMU: Visions and Perspectives" book, Connes starts with some big-picture overview of how one might start with number-theoretic considerations (class field theory) and be led to thinking about modular flow. See pages 1-6 of http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/imufinal.pdf 

Comment: Just to clarify my sketchy comment from above a bit: The $\mathbb R$-action one obtains on the cyclic homology group is induced from the time evolution of the Bost-Connes system (let's say we are working over $\mathbb Q$) which is indeed induced naturally by Tomita-Takesaki theory. Therefore one might view the $\mathbb R$-action on the cyclic homology group coming from TT-theory on the BC-system as an analog of Frobenius in char 0, because it produces in particular a spectral realization of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: This "spectral realization of zeta-functions" might be the answer I'm looking for. Can you tell me more about them. In what sense does the Frobenius provide a spectral realization of a zeta-function? More info about the TT side is also welcome.

Comment: Dear André, I will try to write a detailed answer in the next days. What I can do at least is to explain how Tomita-Takesaki induces the dynamics on the BC-system...;)

Comment: *In what sense does the Frobenius provide a spectral realization of a zeta-function?* The eigenvalues of the Frobenius operator (acting on cohomology groups if you like) are the zeros of the $\zeta$-function, is this sufficient?


Comment: Dear Junkie, by the Hadamard product formula of the Riemann zeta function knowing the non-trivial zeros seems to be sufficient, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Dear Junkie. Thank you for your comment. As you see, I don't know much about zeta functions. When you say "cohomology", are you simply thinking of $H^0(Spec(R),\mathcal O_{Spec(R)})=R$?

Comment: What I mean is, in the "function field" case with the Frobenius action, the (local) $\zeta$-function is just a quotient of polynomials, with roots the eigenvalues of Frobenius on various $H^{\bullet}$. For instance, in elliptic curves, there is that the local factor has $${(1-a_qT+qT^2)\over (1-T)(1-qT)}$$ where $T=q^{-s}$ and $a_q$ is the trace of the $q$-power Frobenius on $H^1$, with $q$ the determinant. In general the even cohomology, $H^0$ and $H^2$ here, appear in the denominator. See "General formulas for the zeta function" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_zeta-function

Comment: @Bora, it's not clear to me what Connes senses by char. 0 analogues. The global $\zeta$-function is a product of local $\zeta$-functions, and the zeros of the local are irrelevant for zeroes of the global object. A colloquial notion of "Frobenius in char 0" is seeming "Frobenius at $\infty$" related to complex conjugation. That Frob affects the $\Gamma$-factors that intervene in the functional equation. Easy example, real quadratic fields have $\Gamma(s/2)^2$, while imaginary has $\Gamma(s/2)\Gamma((s+1)/2)$. So the "char 0 Frob" would have eigenvalues $\pm 1$ given to how $\bar{}$ acts then?

Comment: @Bora... but your comment senses that Connes finds the *global* $\zeta$-function from this modular flow, which quite says it binds more than just how complex conjugation acts (locally) with infinite places. I haven't kept up with their work, but the original formulation (1998) used an adelic presentation so that all places occurred, and the action was via the number field (idele class group). I am unable to parse pages 556ff sufficiently well to tell whether there is anything new beyond more abstruse language.

Comment: Dear Junkie, I agree with you, for me the role of a char 0 Frobenius is also not clear. I will describe in the next days the example of the BC system in some detail. The BC-system combines Frobenii lifts over finite places and "this Frob in char 0" coming from TT theory. Then, Connes et al consider a scaling action (by $\mathbb R$) on this space and this gives (after a lot of work which I, admittedly, do not really understand) a spectral realization of the zeta function (among others). So in fact there are two $\mathbb R$ actions, one of them "interpolating" in some sense all Frobenii....

Comment: ...and giving rise to a spectral realization. But this is not anymore the action coming from TT theory. If I may make another vague statement, in my opinion one of the big obstacles we have in proving the Riemann hypothesis is that we don't have any clue about the archimedean side. It seems clear that $Gal(\mathbb C / \mathbb R)$ cannot be want we are looking for so a good deal of the recent work of Connes deals with the question of what should be the right replacement of this "ridiculously" simple extension $\mathbb C / \mathbb R$. (Much of his "char 1" work is dedicated to this question)

Answer (score 13):

A low tech (naive?) piece of intuition comes straight from the definition of the modular operator and what happens if one tries to carry it over to finite fields.

The nontrivial automorphism $z\mapsto\overline{z}$ in $Gal(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$ is encoded in a von Neumann algebra via the existence of a *-operation $(zX)^\ast=\overline{z}X^\ast$. When $M$ is faithfully represented in a Hilbert space $H$ with cyclic and separating vector $\Omega$ we construct $SX\Omega:=X^\ast\Omega$, then $\Delta:=|S|^2$, then $\sigma_{t}(X)=\Delta^{it}X\Delta^{-it}$, so the modular group encodes $z\mapsto\overline{z}$ in some sense.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and note that the Frobenius automorphism of $F_{p^n}$ generates $Gal(F_{p^n}/F_p)$. Take an associative, unital algebra $R$ over $F_{p^n}$ equipped with a bijection $Q:R\to R$, satisfying $Q(zx)=Fr(z)Q(x)$ for all $z\in F_{p^n}$ and $x\in R$. If $R$ is faithfully represented on an $F_{p^n}$ vector space $V$ with cyclic and separating vector $\Omega$ then we obtain a map $S:V\to V$, $S x\Omega=Q(x)\Omega$, which has the property $$S z\xi=Fr(z)S\xi\quad\hbox{for all}\quad z\in F_{p^n},~\xi\in V.$$ Given such a map $T$ we can extract an $F_{p^n}$-linear map $T^n$ (the analogue of $T\rightarrow |T|^{2i}$ for an antilinear operator). Set $\Delta:=S^n$. As $\Omega$ is cyclic and separating and $Q$ is a bijection, $\Delta$ is invertible and we can form the maps $\sigma_{m}(x)=\Delta^{m} x\Delta^{-m}$ for each $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we find that $\sigma_m$ is an $F_{p^n}$ algebra homomorphism and $\sigma_{m_1}\circ\sigma_{m_2}=\sigma_{m_1+m_2}$. If $R$ is a field over $F_{p^n}$ then we have the canoncial map $Q(x)=x^p$ and $\sigma_m(x)=Fr^{nm}(x)$. This extends easily to the case $R=M_n(K)$ for a field $K$. I'm not sure if a `nice' $Q$ exists for a general division algebra.

Comment: Very nice ☺! Would you guess that your answer was one of Connes' motivations for making his claim? I'm just asking because it feels a bit like an "after the fact" justification...

Comment: No, I don't think he was thinking anything as concrete. Possibly Connes' motivation was that the modular flow plays a similar role in classifying von Neumann algebras to the tools used in classifying local fields. Yemon's reference explains this quite well.